# Binding Select with knockoutjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC4 view i am binding `select` with `ko array`. But the options are not getting populated. Here is my code.

**View**

```
   <select size="5" data-bind="options: featuredContacts">
   </select>
```

**script**

```
    $(function () {

        var contacts = {
            featuredContacts: ko.observableArray(['france', 'germany', 'japan'])
        };
    });
```

Comment: where are you binding your view model? i.e `ko.applyBindings(new contacts());`

Comment: hi thanks @marvc. can you update your comments as answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.applyBindings` needs to be called to bind the view model `contacts` with your html.

```
    $(function () {
        var Contacts = {
            featuredContacts: ko.observableArray(['france', 'germany', 'japan'])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new Contacts());
    });
```